# Bundling JDK/JRE

Tags: licensing, java

I am inquiring into the licensing pertaining to distributing the JDK/JRE from Sun.

The reason I ask is that I would like to provide a client with an ISO disk image that includes my application plus the JDK or JRE dependency.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 8):

This is what you need:

[Form Sun:](http://java.sun.com/javase/faqs.jsp#2q1)

> ***Redistribution:*** Both the JDK and JRE can be freely redistributed with value-add (per terms of the BCL).

Here's [the link](http://java.sun.com/javase/faqs.jsp)

Answer (score 3):

Many people have been bundling the JDK into their applications without paying any fees. The user is not bothered with the licensing issues as the JDK/JRE is already extracted and any other dependency is also bundled.

I often see that question asked but Sun doesn't provide a clear and simple answer to it. "If you would like to embed the JVM in commercial applications, you have to pay some fees". Such a note should be displayed in each download page in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you do not modify it and do not charge money for it, you can bundle the installation binary along with your app.  The jars are not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this information in the Java SE README files.

In particular, this is an extract of the [Java 7 JRE README](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-7-readme-430162.html):

> [...] you can redistribute the Java SE Runtime Environment for free
>   with your application, according to the terms of the Oracle Binary
>   Code License Agreement for the Java  SE Platform Products.

Redistribution of JDK is a bit more complicated, please refer to the `Redistributable JDK Files` section of README file.